# Diferencia entre modos de llamar a una propiedad

Tags: javascript

Leyendo un libro me encontre lo siguiente :

> Una vez creadas las propiedades del objeto, puede accederse a ellas de dos 
>   formas:

```
obj.nombre = "Simon";
var nombre = obj.nombre;
```

y...

```
obj["nombre"] = "Simon";
var nombre = obj["nombre"];
```

> Estas son semánticamente equivalentes. El segundo método tiene la ventaja de que el nombre de la propiedad se ingresa como cadena, lo que significa que puede ser calculado en tiempo de ejecución aunque usar este método impide que se apliquen algunas optimizaciones del motor JavaScript.

¿A que se refiere con 'calculado en tiempo de ejecución' y la otra duda es la relación con el motor de javacript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que son dos preguntas en una, y que incluso la segunda podría ser algo amplia, pero muy interesante si la planteas bien, pero repito, sería un tema aparte.

Me limitaré a responder a tu primera pregunta.

En el ejemplo de código que usa MDN en el apartado [Trabajando con objetos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Trabajando_con_objectos) se puede ver con facilidad los casos en que convendría usar `[]` para definir las propiedades de los objetos.

Supongamos un objeto que tendría, entre sus propiedades, un valor aleatorio. En ese caso, mediante corchetes le podrás asignar ese valor fácilmente:

```js
var miObjeto = new Object(),
    cadena = "miCadena",
    aleatorio = Math.random(),
    options= { year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit',  hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', second: '2-digit'};

    ahora=new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-GB',options),
    objeto = new Object();

miObjeto.type                 = "Sintaxis con punto";
miObjeto["Fecha de creación"] = "Cadena con espacios y acento";
miObjeto[cadena]              = "String value";
miObjeto[aleatorio]           = "Número Aleatorio";
miObjeto[objeto]              = "Objeto";
miObjeto[""]                  = "Incluso una cadena vacía";
miObjeto[ahora]               = "Valor dinámico (fecha y hora)";

console.log(miObjeto);
```

Como se puede ver, la cuarta propiedad del objeto se genera correctamente de forma dinámica en tiempo de ejecución.

---

Sin embargo, de esta forma no es posible.

- El valor *aleatorio* obtenido cada vez en tiempo de ejecución, no se crea como una propiedad del objeto si usas la sintaxis `Objeto.propiedad`. Como se podrá ver en el código, se crea una propiedad cuyo nombre es fijo, no una propiedad con el valor de la variable `aleatorio` obtenida en el Random.
- No se podrá asignar una propiedad como esta, usada más arriba: `Fecha de creación` *so pena* de error.
- No se podrá asignar una cadena vacía `" "` como nombre de propiedad de un objeto.
- No se podrá asignar como nombre de propiedad un objeto (como el objeto fecha creado dinámicamente). En ese caso la propiedad adquiere el valor `Object` en vez del valor contenido dentro de él.

```js
var miObjeto = new Object(),
  cadena = "miCadena",
  aleatorio = Math.random(),

  options = {
    year: 'numeric',
    month: '2-digit',
    day: '2-digit',
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit',
    second: '2-digit'
  },

  ahora = new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-GB', options),

  objeto = new Object();

miObjeto.type      = "Sintaxis con punto";
//Error ->miObjeto.Fecha decreación    = "Cadena con espacios y acento";
miObjeto.cadena    = "String value";
miObjeto.aleatorio = "Número Aleatorio";
miObjeto.objeto    = "Objeto";
//Error ->miObjeto.""                 = "Incluso una cadena vacía";
miObjeto.ahora     = "Valor aleatorio (fecha y hora actual)";


console.log(miObjeto);
```